# using grunt, is it possible to compile and output a single changed file to a different directory?

Tags: node.js, coffeescript, gruntjs

Many coffee source files in `/assets/src/coffee` etc (`./child/paths` and so on) and I'd like to output them to `assets/js/` and `assets/js/child/paths`.

It looks like I've gotten close, but it's not working. Using `grunt-contrib-coffee` and `grunt-contrib-watch`.

```
grunt.initConfig
watch:
  coffee:
    files: '<%= coffee.src %>',
    tasks: 'coffee:dev'
    options:
      nospawn: true

coffee:
  src: 'assets/src/coffee/**/*.coffee'
  dev:
    options:
      sourceMap: true
    files: [
      expand: true
      cwd: "assets/"
      src: "/src/coffee/**/*.coffee"
      dest: "../js/"
      ext: ".js"
    ]

grunt.loadNpmTasks "grunt-contrib-coffee"
grunt.loadNpmTasks 'grunt-contrib-watch' 
# Default task.
grunt.registerTask "default", "watch"

grunt.event.on('watch', (action, filepath) ->
(grunt.log.writeln('\n'+ filepath + ' has ' + action))

dest = "#{path.dirname(filepath.replace("src/coffee", "js"))}"

grunt.config(['coffee', 'dev', 'files', 'src'], [filepath])
grunt.config(['coffee', 'dev', 'files', 'dest'], [dest])

(grunt.log.writeln("src: #{grunt.config(['coffee', 'dev', 'files', 'src'])}"))
(grunt.log.writeln("dest: #{grunt.config(['coffee', 'dev', 'files', 'dest'])}"))
```

)

Ok, so the output of that looks like:

```
assets/src/coffee/projAlpha/dl.coffee has changed    
src: assets/src/coffee/projAlpha/dl.coffee    
dest: assets/js/projAlpha/dl.coffee
```

but the file actually ends up in: `assets/src/coffee/projAlpha/dl.coffee`... and it's coffee script. It should be in `assets/js/projAlpha/dl.js`.

I've gotten the grunt coffee utility to compile *all* the files at once and put them in the right place. I'd rather they got compiled one at a time though, since I've got a few files now and am adding more all the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your glob-pattern file path config, I notice 2 problems:

1. The glob-pattern options do not come under the "files" key, but
   directly under the options key.
2. The CWD is only meant for the src files. The dest directory does not
   use cwd, so you must specify the full path from the base directory
   (where your Gruntfile is).

---

```
dev:
  options:
    sourceMap: true
  expand: true
  cwd: "assets/src/coffee/"
  src: "**/*.coffee"
  dest: "assets/js/"
  ext: ".js"
```

This will move, for example, `assets/src/coffee/User/controller.coffee` to `assets/js/User/controller.js`.

Comment: Hmm not quite: "Warning: EACCES, permission denied '/dev/fd/10'"

Comment: My bad, the "cwd" is supposed to have a trailing slash. I had put it as a leading slash in "src".

Comment: OK that's working, but I already had that working -- in some other code -- but what I'm trying to do is only compile the file that has changed instead of all the files. That's what that `grunt.event.on` is about.